# Incorrect URL in admin section

Tags: django, django-admin

In the admin section of my Django project, all the links are correct, except the *Recent Actions* table.

[image]

This seems to append another "admin" to the URL path, for example, clicking "Applicants on the left hand side, takes me to:

```
https://<IP>/admin/jobs/applicant/
```

Which is fine. However, clicking a Recent Action sends me to the following URL:

```
https://<IP>/admin//admin/jobs/applicant/12/
```

Note the extra "admin/".

Does anyone know where this is defined and how to change it?

Comment: Are you using any custom admin interface?

Comment: No, just the bog standard one.